# Who is Ichigo's Father, Isshin?

Tags: bleach

Though he is initially shown as a normal human, it is later revealed that he once had Shinigami powers, and later he is the only one

> Who knows about Ichigo's true powers, and who tells Ichigo how to train for the last battle against Aizen.

But the The Lost Substitute Shinigami arc where

> Ichigo fights Ginjo, it's revealed that Ginjo was the first Substitute Shinigami.

So what is Ichigo's father and why does he know what he knows? Also, why he doesn't seem to have any Shinigami powers, while he knows so much about them?

Comment: Yeah, Bleach is full of plot holes like that.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it doesn't really seem like a plot hole, I mean there are too many hints about ichigo's father that one might assume there should be a big story (maybe even as big as an arc) behind him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isshin Kurosaki used to be a Shinigami of an unknown division and rank. According to bleach.wikia.com:

> About twenty years ago, he ceased being a Shinigami, losing most of his powers.

He still has a shikai, which he uses during the Fake Karakura arc.

Spoiler:

> Ichigo also has Quincy powers that have been implied to be related to his mother. If Ichigo's mother was a Quincy, Isshin may have known.

Comment: isnt it revealed that isshin is a former captain? as far as i remember he is the captain of the division where Tōshirō Hitsugaya is the captain as of now.

Comment: The wiki claims he was the captain of squad 10 and links to the chapter in the manga that this occurred: http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Isshin_Kurosaki